# how fix docker when goes to restarting status after docker-compose in django on ubuntu

Tags: django, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I use postgresql and docker in my django project. after docker-compose my container goes to restarting status. I tried fix it by stop and remove but didn't work

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  blog_postgresql:
    image: postgres:12
    container_name: blog_postgresql
    volumes:
      - blog_postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - blog_network
volumes:
  blog_postgresql:
    external: true

networks:
  blog_network:
    external: true
```

and terminal show this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                            PORTS               NAMES
e8aa3e604ba3        postgres:12         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 days ago          Restarting (126) 14 seconds ago                       blog_postgresql
```

Answer (score 0):

The restart obviously happens because of `restart: always` in your compose file. 
Usually the reason is an internal error that kills your container which is automatically restarted.

What I'd suggest is to figure out which is the error by taking a look into the `blog_postgresql` logs, with the `docker-compose logs blog_postgresql` command.